# .htaccess Redirect to a URL that uses a rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Redirect like so:

```
Redirect 301 /url-1 /url-2
```

However, `/url-2` matches a rewrite like such:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is redirecting `/url-1` to:

```
/url-2?view=url-1
```

How can I get this to redirect and then rewrite correctly?

Comment: `/url-1` should redirect to `/url-2` and then `/url-2` fullfulls the Rewrite. The final url should be just `/url-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestions:

1. Don't mix `Redirect` directive with `mod_rewrite` rules
2. Keep redirect rules before rewrite rules.
3. Skip files and directories from last rule

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^url-1/? /url-2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: My `/url-1` to `/url-2` is a redirect, rather than a rewrite. Where do I place this?

Comment: `R=301` means it is a redirect not rewrite. If we use `R` flag means it is a redirect.

Comment: So I should have Rewrites rather than redirects?

Comment: Yes that's correct but remember we don't match leading slash `/` in `RewriteRule` like we do in `Redirect`.

Comment: Okay, will the likes of google still pick these up as 301 redirects, yes?

Comment: Yes that's what `R=301` is used for.